# Java Hibernate Lazy=false

Tags: java, hibernate

When setting `Lazy=false`, then hibernate will automatically loads the objects into the required sets e.g.

```
<set name="Options" table="ATTRIBUTEOPTION" inverse="false"  cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key>
            <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.AttributeOption" />
</set>
```

but if in my xml mapping, I place lazy=true and in some place in my application i decide that i want to load all attribute options, should i do it manually, or is there a technique which lets tells hibernate that now i want to set `lazy=false`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the configuration at runtime. But you can use `Hiberante.initialize(..)` to initialize lazy collections.

Answer (score 3):

Yo can do it manually simply using getOptions(). But if when loading the entity you already now that you will need the options then you can do an eager fetch using fetch join this way:

```
 select c from EntityX c left join fetch c.Options
```

And it's an important optimitzation beacuse you can avoid a lot of extra selects if you prefetch data that you will know that will be needed.

Comment: Ya, I have included hibernate in my project, now i need to get down to optimization!!